# Grafana LDAP created user can't login through REST API

Tags: python, ldap, grafana, grafana-api

I am using the Grafana with my Django App and creating the user in the LDAP server. I wanted to make the user to Grafana admin at the time at the creating the user in the LDAP server. I found REST API [Doc](https://grafana.com/docs/http_api/admin/#permissions) to set the user as grafanaAdmin, for this, it's required `user-id` and I am falling to find the user-id before the actual user logged in via browsers.

I tried some way to get the created user's `:id`

```
import requests

url = "http://localhost:3000/api/user"

auth = ("username","password",)

response = requests.request("GET", url, auth=auth)

print(response.text)
```

This code not giving me the user `:id` before the user actually logged in to the Grafana server.
Is there any other way to get the user `:id`